# Dealing with @Nullable in FunctionalInterface lambda

Tags: java-8, checker-framework

How should I deal with lambda functions using checker-framework typed annotations?

For example,

```
private void dispatch(Progress progress, Load request, @Nullable Layer layer)
    {
        if (layer == null) return;

        Utils.log("DISPATCHING " + layer.name);
        JThread.run(() -> runDispatch(progress, request, layer));
    }
```

Checker will issue a `argument.type.incompatible` warning on the `runDispatch` line call, even though `layer` is being checked beforehand. I understand that the lambda function is inside a different context, and therefore Checker can't correctly assess that. What is the best way to deal with it?

**Extra info**

Full warning:

```
error: [argument.type.incompatible] incompatible types in argument.
[ERROR] found   : @Initialized @Nullable Layer<? extends @Initialized @NonNull Item, ? extends @Initialized @NonNull Deliver, ? extends @Initialized @NonNull Recipient>
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] required: @Initialized @NonNull Layer<? extends @Initialized @NonNull Item, ? extends @Initialized @NonNull Deliver, ? extends @Initialized @NonNull Recipient>
```

`runDispatch`is declared on the same class, signature `private void runDispatch(Progress progress, Load request, Layer layer)`

**Another example:**
Elsewhere in my code I have a similar situation, but involving method behavior:

on `Item.class`:

```
    @EnsuresNonNullIf(expression="extraAction", result=true)
    public final boolean hasExtraAction() {
        return extraAction != null;
    }
```

on a separate class:

```
    @RequiresNonNull("#2.extraAction")
    private void buildExtraActionRunnable(Layer layer, Item item, Deliver deliver) {
    ....
    }



    ...
    } else if (item.hasExtraAction()) {
            Runnable r = () -> buildExtraActionRunnable(layer, item, deliver);
```

Here, at the Runnable line I get `error: [contracts.precondition.not.satisfied] the called method 'buildExtraActionRunnable(layer, item, deliver)' has a precondition 'item.extraAction' that is not satisfied`

Comment: What is the exact warning that is being issued?  And, how is `runDispatch` defined?  If you can provide a MWE (as a complete compiliable file), that would be helpful.

Comment: @mernst added to my answer. A bit hard to provide a MWE as there're lots of dependencies, but if still necessary ask me.

Comment: In the first example, `layer` must be effectively final to be captured by the lambda expression, so it can’t change to `null` after the check. It’s the principle of lambda expressions (unlike inner classes) that the variables do *not* live in a different context. I’d call the failure to recognize the validity a flaw of the checker. The second example is not so clear. If `item.extraAction` is mutable, the validity can’t be proven, unless the `Runnable` never escapes the scope of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that this is a [bug](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/issues/1248) in the [Nullness Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-checker).
In this part of your code:

```
    Utils.log("DISPATCHING " + layer.name);
    JThread.run(() -> runDispatch(progress, request, layer));
```

the Nullness Checker knows at the call of `Utils.log` that `layer` is non-null, but it doesn't know that fact at the call to `runDispatch` within the method body.  Within the method body, it is using the *declared* type of `layer` rather than a *refined* type computed via dataflow analysis.

Your question was how to work around the Checker Framework bug.
One way to do so is to introduce a new variable:

```
    Utils.log("DISPATCHING " + layer.name);
    Layer layer2 = layer;  // work around CF issue #1248
    JThread.run(() -> runDispatch(progress, request, layer2));
```

The above code typechecks correctly.

I can't give a detailed answer for your second example, because you didn't give a compilable MWE.  But whenever there is an error of the form `error: [KEY] ...`, you can always suppress it by adding `@SuppressWarnings("KEY")`.  It your case, this would be `@SuppressWarnings("contracts.precondition.not.satisfied")`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a workaround suggestion for method behavior in example #2?